# How can I concatenate an INDEX MATCH formula from one sheet based off another ?

Tags: excel

I've got down the INDEX MATCH and tried a VLOOKUP. INDEX MATCH worked for me to an extent.

I've got a master sheet that has 524 player names, teams, etc on it. Then I have another sheet "batter stats" on it. On both pages there is a QTY field that you can input the quantity of the cards that you own of that player.

What I'm trying to do is have an INDEX MATCH lookup the players name matching them on both sheets and inputting the quantity from the master sheet onto the batter stats sheet. Which this works though the problem is on the master sheet there are batters and pitchers. So the quantity will come up but not in the right cell. You can notice by the card number on the left as well.

```
=INDEX(Main!F2:F156,MATCH(B2,B2:B38,0))
```

I was told/suggested to concatenate information so not only look for the players name but the pose on the card for instance. Does anyone have any suggestions/answers for this?

[image: ***strong text***MAIN PAGE]

[image: ***BATTER STATS***]

Comment: If you are looking for a collective total, a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) may be appropriate.

Comment: That would not be able to determine the player though. The main page has players (batters & pitchers). I'm trying to find only the batters on the front page by matching their names. I could do a simple = and reference the main page but I feel like there's a simpler and more professional way to do this.

Comment: So you are trying to filter the results by Pose=Batting?

Comment: I'm just trying to match up the names and if there is a quantity on the main page add it to the batter page. THE PROBLEM is that the two pages aren't aligned for example cards 1,2,3,4 are all on the main page but card # 5 Doc Adkins is not on the batter page so his quantity should NOT be added to the batter page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the card number is unique and static for each, you can just use a VLOOKUP on the Batter sheet, referencing the Master sheet.
Something like:

```
    =VLOOKUP(A1,Main!$A$2:$A$156,7,FALSE)
```

Replace 156 with the total number of rows in your Main sheet and copy the formula down the column in your Batter sheet.

Comment: Sorry, I slipped up on the formula, replace with =VLOOKUP(A1,Main!$A$2:$G$156,7,FALSE)

Comment: This is getting tricky now and I apologize I didn't point it out before but the main page has the QTY in the 6th column batter page has it in the 7th. I tried reworking that LOOKUP with the other numbers but still got a #N/A ............... weird.

Comment: In that case you would just need to change the third variable to 6 instead of 7.  And it doesn't matter where it is on the batter page, since you're putting the formula where you want it to go.